# Azure communications Web Calling issue

Tags: azure-communication-services

When i use the **`CallClient`** of **@azure/communication-calling SDK** to create a CallAgent, i'm getting '**No CommunicationTokenCredential provided**' error even though i'm passing a valid CommunicationTokenCredential
Ex: `this.callAgent = await this.callClient.createCallAgent(tokenCredential);`

I'm able to successfully deploy a standalone react app & run the following sample application and make a web call as suggested in Microsoft docs. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-tutorial

But, when I integrate this into my existing React App, I start having issues in creating a `CallAgent` with the following error:

> 'azure:ACS:error 27/10/2021, 18:13:48:96 CallClient1:CallAgent1 op:Initialize failed, message=No CommunicationTokenCredential provided,'

I am passing the `CommunicationTokenCredential` properly while calling the `createCallAgent(token)` (verified by printing the token as well).
But still, I get this error. Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/253621/39azurecommunicationusercredential39-was-not-found.html Did you tried this work around?

Comment: @Techidiot : Thanks for the link. Apparently, i'm using AzureCommunicationTokenCredential as suggested by microsoft folks in the response to that thread. But, still i get the same error.